# RAD Studio Delphi 10.4(0) and BigSur

Tags: macos, delphi, macos-big-sur

Application compiled with RAD Studio Delphi 10.4(.0) don't works in macOS Bug Sur.
I have tryed to install SDK 11.1 in but compilation rise a
*"[dccosx64 Fatal Error] F2588 Linker error code: 1 ($00000001)"*
error.
It is necessary to update RAD Studio to version 10.4.2 or maybe something in new SDK installation go wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By Googling 30 seconds, I found this: [apple-platforms-patch-for-rad-studio-10-4-1](https://blogs.embarcadero.com/fr/apple-platforms-patch-for-rad-studio-10-4-1/).

If 10.4.1 needs a patch for Big Sur, probably 10.4.0 can't do it.

Comment: Thank you, but I know this patch. 
Actually we have only licecnse for RAD Studo 10.4.0 and we hope application compiled and running under Catalina are also running on Big Sur, without new complier version.